# Ironing Board Material

Tags: fabric

I like to iron our sheets, but it take forever on our regular ironing board. I bought some "cotton ironing board material" at my local fabic store. It seems to be the same type of material used to make ironing board covers.

I plan to place the fabric over a 4' folding table. My question is, what exactly is the ironing board material for?  Is it to protect the board or table?  Does the silver material help get the wrinkles out of whatever you are ironing? I can't seem to find any information on the benefit of using the silver material. 
Thank you

Comment: If it's made from *coated* cotton fibres, the cotton will stay drier as it will absorb less steam.  That steam may then be available to do its job.  Cheap Ironing boards often use normal fabric covers anyway, so it's not essential

Answer (score 1):

When I first read your question, my answer was going to be that your "regular" ironing board has a metal surface in direct contact with the fabric covering. As such, it pulls heat from the iron without providing the benefit to the fabric being ironed.

In the case of the silver material, it is likely that it reflects the heat energy back toward the iron, also insulating the surface below. There should be some thickness to the silver material providing that insulating capacity. If not, even a thick towel will improve the insulation and protective ability of the silver covering.

One listing I found states that the material is one hundred percent cotton, then references an aluminized coating. It cannot be one hundred percent cotton, as aluminum is not cotton, but that is semantics.

Comment: The fabric can be 100% cotton with an aluminized coating. Clearly a composite material. That is a technical description and not "semantics".